# How to select a XML-attribute using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML where I would like to select a specific attribute.
One entry in the XML looks like:

```
<show time="27652">
  <user cn="User5" guid="abc" e164="15" h323="User5" text="100000" loc="Everywhere" node="root" filter="normal" cd-filter="normal" reporting="true" uclic="true" type="ep">
    <presence c="tel:" s="closed" a="vacation"/>
    <device hw="user-5"/>
    <grp name="TAPI"/>
    <grp name="soap"/>
  </user>
</show>
```

To show me this User I have also a function to display the user:

```
function do_show(array $options) {
    global $showresult, $master;
    $cn = "User5";
    $config = $options["config"]->value;
    $show = new SimpleXMLElement("<show/>");
    $user = $show->addChild("user");
    $user->addAttribute("cn", $cn);
    print_r($show);
    if ($config)
        $user->addAttribute("config", "true");

    print "cmd: " . htmlspecialchars($show->asXML()) . "\n";
    $showresult = $master->Admin($show->asXML());
    print "result: " . htmlspecialchars($showresult) . "\n";
}
```

This displays me the output above. However if I would like to display for example the users with text="100000" I changed following lines of code:

```
$cn = "100000";
....
$user->addAttribute("text", $cn);
```

This does not work, and it displays me nothing. Although I changed it to text=100000.

I also print_r the variable $show to see if there is something wrong. Before change:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [user] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
            [@attributes] => Array (
                    [cn] => User5
                )
        )
)
```

After modification:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [user] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
            [@attributes] => Array (
                    [text] => 100000
                )
        )
)
```

This looks also fine to me. So, where is my mistake?

$showresult is null and $master are the connection details...
Thank you very much.